azcopy not working when authenticated without using SAS tokens
got a storage account using a private endpoint connection, i am trying to move the cotainers onto a different storage account. Using the azcopy utility as it appears to be the only way. if there are other ways, please share and show an example.
logged in using azcopy login
completed the process by adding the code on the browser.
Ran the below.
.\azcopy.exe copy 'https://source.blob.core.windows.net/myblob' 'https://destination.blob.core.windows.net/myblob' --recursive

Got the owner role assigned at the storage account level, set the owner role at the container level also.
Got the errors below.
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason GET https://source.blob.core.windows.net/partest
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ERROR CODE: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:9d61xxx
Time:2024-06-06T16:35:51.0384547Z</Message></Error>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

What also surprises me is this.
If i try to copy the blob from one account to the other, using the SAS tokens I get an error.
.\azcopy.exe  copy 'https://source.blob.core.windows.net/?SAS-TOKEN' 'https://destination.blob.core.windows.net/?SAS-TOKEN' --recursive

However, if I download one container at a time locally, then upload it using azcopy and thesame SAS token, it works.
This is what works.
.\azcopy.exe  copy 'https://source.blob.core.windows.net/container/?TOKEN'  'D:\temp'  --recursive

then upload
.\azcopy.exe  copy  "D:\blob\analyticsstaggingarea" "https://destination.blob.core.windows.net/container?TOKEN" --recursive


Are you creating SAS token for destination account? or using same source account SAS token to destination URL?

The sas tokens ae not thesame, otherwise the upload wouldnt work. I think something is fundamentally broken somewhere. I read somewhere that where an & is wthin the SAS token, it needs to be doubled and presented as &&


azcopy not working when authenticated without using SAS tokens

In my environment, I assigned owner role at the storage account level.
Portal:

Now, I tried the same command and got the same error.
Command and error:
PS C:\Users\xxxxx> azcopy  login

INFO: Login succeeded.
INFO: azcopy.exe 10.22.2: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

PS C:\Users\xxx> azcopy copy "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test" "https://xxxx6.blob.core.windows.net/sample" --recursive
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: azcopy.exe 10.22.2: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason GET https://venkat456.blob.core.windows.net/test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ERROR CODE: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:ad0e545d-301e-001c-78d0-b835eb000000
Time:2024-06-07T11:46:04.9997008Z</Message></Error>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.

PS C:\Users\xxxx>

Error:

To copy files to different storage accounts you need Storage Blob Data Contributor at resource grp level.
I assigned the role at resource grp level.
Portal:

Now, I ran the same command in my environment it executed successfully.
Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxx> azcopy copy "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test" "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/sample" --recursive
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: azcopy.exe 10.22.2: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job e6caf1xxxx3c3296 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\xxx\.azcopy\e6caf164-228a-304a-547bx-3x3345a3xxc3296.log

INFO: Transfers could fail because AzCopy could not verify if the destination supports tiers.
100.0 %, 6 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 6 Total,


Job e6caf164-22xxx45a3c3296 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0671
Number of File Transfers: 6
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 6
Number of File Transfers Completed: 6
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 2974906
Final Job Status: Completed

PS C:\Users\vxxxu>


The above command copied successful between two storage account without using SAS token.
Portal:

Reference:
Authorize access to blobs & files with AzCopy & Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft Learn
